# Dynamic load classes - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the wrong path
I want to load dynamic classes
I Use this function

```
 function settings($setting = 'General')
    {
        $settings = "App\Settings\\" . $setting . "Settings::class";
        return app($settings);
    }
```

I get an error

```
Target class [App\Settings\GeneralSettings::class] does not exist.
```

When I use this it works

```
app(App\Settings\GeneralSettings::class)
```

How can I fix that

Comment: `::class` is not part of the Classname; it's a static property that returns `App\Settings\GeneralSetting`. Just remove `::class` and it should work. Also yes, `app(App\Settings\GeneralSettings::class)` works, but does `app("App\Settings\GeneralSettings::class")` (it shouldn't)? Cause that's what you're passing to it via `$settings`

Comment: Now it works after removing ::class